# can not deserialize Json Object to Type

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have an below Json  object,I am trying to Deserialize json object to "type" but its shows an error message as

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
> into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[KHDataSynch.response]'
> because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
> correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
> (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
> .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
> type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
> object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
> to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'response', line 2, position
> 14.

Please check my below code and advise how to solve this issue.

Json Data :

```
{
  "response": 
    {
      "uri": "\/api\/junaid@khindia.com",
      "action": "MYWORKSPACELIST",
      "result": [{"workspaceId":"2102454000005681734","workspaceName":"Zoho Desk Analytics (Sample)-Copy","workspaceDesc":"Zoho Desk Analytics reporting database providing insightful reports and dashboards on the Help desk data collected.","orgId":"698551553","createdTime":"1596886142038","createdBy":"junaid@khindia.com","isDefault":false},{"workspaceId":"2102454000005398071","workspaceName":"MyData","workspaceDesc":"","orgId":"698551553","createdTime":"1596095878304","createdBy":"junaid@khindia.com","isDefault":false},{"workspaceId":"2102454000005201413","workspaceName":"GloveOrder","workspaceDesc":"","orgId":"698551553","createdTime":"1595582160570","createdBy":"junaid@khindia.com","isDefault":false},{"workspaceId":"2102454000003663782","workspaceName":"TAD","workspaceDesc":"","orgId":"698551553","createdTime":"1591781832434","createdBy":"junaid@khindia.com","isDefault":false},{"workspaceId":"2102454000003605784","workspaceName":"Glove Factory","workspaceDesc":"This workspace for factory people to develop Reports and Dashboards","orgId":"698551553","createdTime":"1591618269812","createdBy":"junaid@khindia.com","isDefault":false},{"workspaceId":"2102454000001881026","workspaceName":"FWD","workspaceDesc":"This is for Shoes Division","orgId":"698551553","createdTime":"1583817905690","createdBy":"junaid@khindia.com","isDefault":false},{"workspaceId":"2102454000000664009","workspaceName":"HO Details","workspaceDesc":"","orgId":"698551553","createdTime":"1580642044086","createdBy":"junaid@khindia.com","isDefault":false},{"workspaceId":"2102454000000323397","workspaceName":"KH Retail","workspaceDesc":"","orgId":"698551553","createdTime":"1578720947711","createdBy":"junaid@khindia.com","isDefault":false},{"workspaceId":"2102454000000319814","workspaceName":"H & S","workspaceDesc":"","orgId":"698551553","createdTime":"1578664170637","createdBy":"junaid@khindia.com","isDefault":false},{"workspaceId":"2102454000000245988","workspaceName":"Teamwork Projects - Sample","workspaceDesc":"","orgId":"698551553","createdTime":"1578224003870","createdBy":"junaid@khindia.com","isDefault":false},{"workspaceId":"2102454000000245069","workspaceName":"Facebook Page competitive Analytics (Sample)","workspaceDesc":"Facebook Competitive Analytics workspace providing insightful comparison reports and dashboards from the data collected from your competitors.","orgId":"698551553","createdTime":"1578223755327","createdBy":"junaid@khindia.com","isDefault":false},{"workspaceId":"2102454000000239193","workspaceName":"Shopify Analytics - Sample","workspaceDesc":"Shopify Analytics workspace providing insightful reports and dashboards on the data collected.","orgId":"698551553","createdTime":"1578223215548","createdBy":"junaid@khindia.com","isDefault":false},{"workspaceId":"2102454000000228568","workspaceName":"Zoho Finance Advanced Analytics  (Sample)","workspaceDesc":"Zoho Finance Analytics reporting database providing insightful reports and dashboards on the data collected.","orgId":"698551553","createdTime":"1578223092773","createdBy":"junaid@khindia.com","isDefault":false},{"workspaceId":"2102454000000227303","workspaceName":"Super Store Sales","workspaceDesc":"Super Store Sales database with sales data for the last 5 years","orgId":"698551553","createdTime":"1578222583948","createdBy":"junaid@khindia.com","isDefault":false},{"workspaceId":"2102454000000216894","workspaceName":"Zoho People - Sample-Copy","workspaceDesc":"","orgId":"698551553","createdTime":"1578221159551","createdBy":"junaid@khindia.com","isDefault":false},{"workspaceId":"2102454000000044365","workspaceName":"Gloves","workspaceDesc":"This is for Gloves Data","orgId":"698551553","createdTime":"1576594180567","createdBy":"junaid@khindia.com","isDefault":true},{"workspaceId":"2102454000000004001","workspaceName":"LGD","workspaceDesc":"","orgId":"698551553","createdTime":"1576246723570","createdBy":"junaid@khindia.com","isDefault":false}]
  }
}
```

C# Code :

```
 public class result
    {
        public string workspaceId { get; set; }
        public string workspaceName { get; set; }
        public string workspaceDesc { get; set; }
        public string orgId { get; set; }
        public string createdTime { get; set; }
        public string createdBy { get; set; }
        public bool isDefault { get; set; }
        
    }
    public class response
    {
        public string uri { get; set; }
        public string action { get; set; }
        public List<result> result { get; set; }

    }

public void GetWorkSpaceList(IReportClient rc)
        {
            try
            {                
               string uri = rc.GetURI(EMAIL);
               string result = rc.MyWorkspaceList(uri, null);

                **List<response> res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<response>>(result);**


            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                XtraMessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your data is the representation of a single object, not a list/array. Deserialize it to a `response`, **not** to a `List<response>`

Comment: Thanks for reply...I have tried above code but value returns null

Comment: @Cid says that : `response res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<response>(result);` Btw your class and method names are confusing. You says `GetWorkSpaceList` but nothing returns. `response` object's name is starting with lowercase and also including a property named `result`. And it's type also `List<result>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. Your outer JSON structure is an object, not a list - which is what the error message is telling you. It can't convert something which isn't a list into a C# list structure.
2. You're mising an outer class to represent the outer JSON object - all you've got is the result and response parts - but they are both structures *within* the outer wrapper.

You need this class structure:

```
   public class Result    {
     public string workspaceId { get; set; } 
     public string workspaceName { get; set; } 
     public string workspaceDesc { get; set; } 
     public string orgId { get; set; } 
     public string createdTime { get; set; } 
     public string createdBy { get; set; } 
     public bool isDefault { get; set; } 
   }

   public class Response    {
     public string uri { get; set; } 
     public string action { get; set; } 
     public List<Result> result { get; set; } 
  }

  public class Root    {
     public Response response { get; set; } 
  }
```

(auto-generated by pasting your JSON into https://json2csharp.com/ - it's a very handy tool.)

and then you can write

```
Root data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(result);
//and to get a specific piece of data, you could write, for example:
var action = data.response.action;
```